# rewiring 2d Grid Network

Tags: python, networkx

I know there are options in `Networkx` for rewiring a network like watts_Strogatz network that we determine it in this way : 
`G=nx.watts_strogatz_network(n,m,p)` that n is the number of nodes , m is the nearest nodes are connected and p is probability of rewiring . 
Now I have a grid network that is periodic . so all the nodes have degree=4 . I want to rewire it to get close to something 2d small-world network . how should I do it ?